# how do you create data frame and merge 2 data frame based on the same column data in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to create 2 data frame in pyton:

```
print(data)
"Hyper","Host","type","cpu","version","status","ncpu","memory"
hpe123,server1,ProLiant DL580 G7,95896010480,5.5.0,POWER_ON,40,549744910336
hpe124,server1,ProLiant DL580 G7,95896010480,5.5.0,POWER_ON,40,549744910336
hpe124,server1,ProLiant DL580 G7,95896010480,5.5.0,POWER_ON,40,549744910336

print(data1)
"clu_name","Hyper"
clu500,hpe123
clu501,hpe123
clu500,hpe123
```

Expected output:

```
clu500, hpe123,server1,ProLiant DL580 G7,95896010480,5.5.0,POWER_ON,40,549744910336
Clu500, hpe124,server1,ProLiant DL580 G7,95896010480,5.5.0,POWER_ON,40,549744910336
```

I need put data and data1 in data frames and merge them to come up with one data frame. Merging needs to happen based on 2nd field in data1 data frame.

I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df1=pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: Please, provide more info on 1) how you want to merge your data and 2) what is the initial type of your data, is it a list, a string, a dictionary, or something else?

Comment: `data1` has two rows with "hpe123". Which should be the one to merge on?

Comment: @not_speshal, I need to merge it based on hpe123 column.

Comment: @user1471980 - That's still confusing. Please post your expected output. Also consider adding appropriate column headers.

Comment: @not_speshal, I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

You need `io.StringIO` to read csv from a string variable.

Try:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = """
Hyper,Host,type,cpu,version,status,ncpu,memory
hpe123,server1,ProLiant DL580 G7,95896010480,5.5.0,POWER_ON,40,549744910336
hpe124,server1,ProLiant DL580 G7,95896010480,5.5.0,POWER_ON,40,549744910336
hpe124,server1,ProLiant DL580 G7,95896010480,5.5.0,POWER_ON,40,549744910336
"""

data1 = """
clu_name,Hyper
clu500,hpe123
clu501,hpe123
clu500,hpe123
"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data))
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data1))

result = df2.merge(df1, on="Hyper")

>>> result
  clu_name   Hyper     Host  ...    status  ncpu        memory
0   clu500  hpe123  server1  ...  POWER_ON    40  549744910336
1   clu501  hpe123  server1  ...  POWER_ON    40  549744910336
2   clu500  hpe123  server1  ...  POWER_ON    40  549744910336
```

Comment: I am getting this error: name 'io' is not defined

Comment: There is an `import io` at the first line. Did you do that?